# how to use IO monad output on fly

Tags: haskell, monads

This is what I am doing:

```
data Person = Person (IORef String) (IORef Int)
name <- newIORef "Boston"
age <- newIORef 100
p = Person name age
```

I am wondering if I can put them in one line, like:

```
p = Person (newIORef "Boston") (newIORef (100::Int))
```

Is there any way to put them in one line?

Comment: Please edit your question so that the syntax is correct (you probably intended to have a do-block in the first piece of code).

Comment: @duplode, To be fair this is a valid ghci session

Comment: @luqui That does make sense. I will keep that in mind while reading questions from now on :)

Answer (score 8):

You can, using the `IO` instance for `Applicative`:

```
p <- Person <$> newIORef "Boston" <*> newIORef 100
```

If you're using an older version of `base` you might have to

```
import Control.Applicative
```

to get `<$>` and `<*>`.

As an aside, in other languages (Agda, Idris) there is a spicy notation called [idiom brackets](https://personal.cis.strath.ac.uk/conor.mcbride/pub/she/idiom.html) which makes things such as this very nice. If we had them in [GHC](https://ocharles.org.uk/IdiomBrackets.html) we could write this code like this instead (which is just notation for the above code):

```
p <- (| Person (newIORef "Boston") (newIORef 100) |)
```

Which one might think leads to nicer code.

Comment: You can also use `liftA2`.